# BeautifulSoup not downloading files as expected

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to download all the .txt files from [this](http://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/props/volume-1/data/) website with the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib 
import urllib2

baseurl = "http://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/props/volume-1/data/"

soup = bs(urllib2.urlopen(baseurl), 'lxml')
links = soup.findAll("a")
for link in links:
    print link.text
    urllib.urlretrieve(baseurl+link.text, link.text)
```

When I run this code, the `print(link.text)` line prints the correct file names and the directory gets populated with files with the correct names, but the contents of the files look something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /props/volume-1/data/ ance_8.5x6_2849cm_4000.txt was not found on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at m-selig.ae.illinois.edu Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Thus, I'm sure the communication is working, but I'm not instructing BS correctly on how to save the contents of the files.

Also, I'm currently downloading all the files with the `findAll("a")` command, but I would actually like to only download specific files with names such as `*geom.txt`

Comment: Why is there a space in here `data/ ance_8`? There shouldn't be. That isn't the content of the file, it is a default error page.

Comment: Hi. Not sure? This is however not something I can change?

Comment: You could write a little bit of code to remove (replace()) the space each time, before attempting to retrieve the page.

Comment: Would you be willing to help me with that in an answer? Perhaps you can then also address the second part of my question relating to downloading only specific files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pull the href to get the link, you can also get just links that contain `geom.txt` using a css selector:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib
import urllib2
from urlparse import urljoin


baseurl = "http://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/props/volume-1/data/"




soup = bs(urllib2.urlopen(baseurl), 'lxml')
links = (a["href"] for a in soup.select("a[href*=geom.txt]"))
for link in links:
    urllib.urlretrieve(urljoin(baseurl, link), link)
```

`a[href*=geom.txt]` finds all anchor tags that have a href with `geom.txt`, it is equivalent to using `if substring in main_string` in python.

You could also use `$=` in your css to find hrefs ending in `geom.txt`:

```
links = (a["href"] for a in soup.select("a[href$=geom.txt]"))
```

Comment: Thank you. This code however produces no output. The code runs for a while, without error, but after that there is nothing.

Comment: @Jonny, it gets all files that contains `geom.txt`, I have run the code myself

Comment: OK might be something with my setup then. Do you use both urllib and urllib2? In your example you only umport the one.

Comment: @Jonny, if you run exactly as posted it will get you all the files saving them as what you see in the href

Comment: NameError: name 'urllib2' is not defined. However, if I import urllib2, I get the response as described in the first comment. Should the files be downloaded to the working directory or somewhere else?

Comment: The files will be in the same cwd, if you want to save to a particular folder then use `"/path/to/{}".format(link)` in place of the second link  in the urlretrieve call

Comment: Now its working, not sure what changed since your last code edit, but anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are reading the text of the links, not the href, and the text contains an extra space. This retrieves the hrefs:

```
links = soup.findAll("a", href=True)
for link in links:
    print link['href']
    urllib.urlretrieve(baseurl+link['href'], link['href'])
```

> I would actually like to only download specific files with names such as *geom.txt

Within the loop you can check, for example, `if "geom" in link['href']:`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use link['href'] instead of the text. In this way you would not have the space which is in the presentation:

```
<li><a href="ance_8.5x6_2850cm_5004.txt"> ance_8.5x6_2850cm_5004.txt</a></li>
```

In the text you have: " ance_8.5x6_2850cm_5004.txt" and in the 'href' field you have "ance_8.5x6_2850cm_5004.txt", without the spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib 
import urllib2

baseurl = "http://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/props/volume-1/data/"

soup = bs(urllib2.urlopen(baseurl), 'lxml')
links = soup.findAll("a")
for link in links:
    print link.text
    data = urllib.urlopen(baseurl+link.text.strip())
    with open(link.text,"wb") as fs:
        fs.write(data.read())
```

Use strip() function to remove the spaces from your url and it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks, this is the first answer to actually work out of the box.

Comment: your welcome, to download files with pattern names in it use @Padraic's answer. Its quite easy to understand.